# Rails 4 - Heroku, can't push, precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

When I attempt to push my app to Heroku, it fails and I get this error:

```
       Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...AwesomeEotPath:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "  'fontawesome-..."
   (in /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
   (sass):7150
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in `expected'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1067:in `expr!'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:794:in `pseudo'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:672:in `simple_selector_sequence'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:640:in `_selector'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:619:in `selector'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:155:in `directive'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in `block_child'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_dff3b836-b2e8-484b-a8ea-cdcf1febef51/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

The app will load, but none of my assets are loaded. My **application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

.table td.center, .table th.center {
   text-align: center;
}
```

I'm not too sure what is going on here or how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is right there. Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss

Comment: @Iceman I pasted the wrong error. The actual error I'm getting is edited above.

Comment: There is a syntax error in some of your scss files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...AwesomeEotPath:": expected
>   pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "  'fontawesome-..."

You problem is you're trying to load a method which the SASS preprocessor doesn't understand. It looks like the method in question is `AwesomeEotPath`, but I can't be sure without seeing the offending code.

When you precompile your assets, it basically takes everything in your `asset manifest` (the `require` parts at the top of your file), and compiles them into the `application.css` (or whatever your file is called)

You mention your file is structured as so:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

I'd recommend your errors will be caused by one of the `require_tree .` includes that you've got in your file. You should post any other CSS files & CSS dependencies you have in your app. For example, if you've called the [`font-awesome-rails` gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails), you'll might have to disable this

If you post your other CSS & Gemfile, we'll be in a better position to help you